# From CD table return artists with more than 1 CD

Tags: mysql, sql

So the Table structure is this

```
          CD id        |          Artist id
```

I want to return artists that appear more than once in this table, as in with more than one CD.

I'm using Mysql so what is the best SQL query to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you group your records by the artist_id, then you can use the `HAVING` clause, which allows you to filter data based on an aggregate, such as `COUNT`, or `SUM`

```
SELECT Artist_id, COUNT(1)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Artist_id
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Short explanation:
This query will select the artist, as well as a count of the number of times they are in the table (Number of CDs in this instance)

This `COUNT` is aggregated on the `GROUP BY` clause, so it will count each grouping of `Artist_Id`

The `HAVING` clause then says that we only want to return records that have a `COUNT(1) > 1` which will indicate number of CDs for this table.

Comment: it would be wonderful if you can give a short explanation as I've been out of touch with SQL :)

Comment: why doesn't                                                         SELECT DISTINCT Artist_id from my_table HAVING COUNT(Artist_id)>1;  work?

Comment: This approach would work, but you would also have to add `GROUP BY Artist_id` between your `FROM` and `HAVING` statements.  I also went with my approach because this type of question often leads to "and how many CDs does each artist have" so I was in that mindset when I started :)

Comment: If I want to get the Artist with most CDs then what would be the query?

Comment: I will take a look, but this should probably be a new question

Comment: @ShyamLovesToCode: to get the one with the most add 'order by 2, 1 limit 1'.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Artist_id, COUNT(0) as `cdCount`
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Artist_id
HAVING cdCount > 1;
```

This should give you the artists with more than 1 cd (Adam has already explained)

To get the one with the max cds, there are 2 ways:

(a) You order by the count and then select the first

```
SELECT Artist_id, COUNT(0) as cdCount
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Artist_id
HAVING cdCount > 1
ORDER BY cdCount
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

However, this will not give you all artists if you have more than 1 artists with the max # of cds

In that case, use

(b)

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT Artist_id, COUNT(0) as cdCount
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Artist_id) t
HAVING cdCount = MAX(t.cdCount);
```